# Spring MVC with non english chars and method post

Tags: mysql, spring, jsp, encoding

I have form in jsp with send button:

```
 <form role="form" action="/admin/newUserTest/" method="post">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" name="lastname">
       <input type ="send" value="Send">
</form>
```

And Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/newUserTest", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView newUserTest(@RequestParam("firstname")String firstname,@RequestParam("lastname")String lastname){
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    System.out.println(firstname);
    System.out.println(lastname);
  ...
```

And firstname and lastname I write in table(mysql). When method="get" it writes correct , but when method ="post" it writes wrong symbols like ÑÐ·ÐµÑ3. And console writes symbols like ???·?µ??3 .
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What was `ÑÐ·ÐµÑ3` supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem, add to web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is due to spring is not able to use correct encoding. 
Make sure to register CharacterEncodingFilter in your web.xml

```
 <filter>  
<filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>  
<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>  
<init-param>  
   <param-name>encoding</param-name>  
   <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>  
</init-param>  
<init-param>  
   <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>  
   <param-value>true</param-value>  
</init-param>  
</filter>  
<filter-mapping>  
  <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>  
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
</filter-mapping>
```

If you are using Java class based configurations. Use

```
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Hope it helps to resolve the issue.